# Redis Stack Server - Cannot Change Data Dir (Docker/Kubernetes)

Tags: configuration, redis, troubleshooting

I am trying to get redis up and running in a Kubernetes environment. I’ve done many tutorials, read the documentation, etc. etc. I need to have the .rdb file and the .aof file(s) saved in a Persistent Volume so that the data can be persisted across Pod (or container) failures/deletions/etc. I have a redis instance starting, and I’m *trying* to use a custom config file. All the pods get created and run fine and the `save` and `appendonly` variables in the custom config file are updated/correct (the others are the default values). However, neither the `daemonize` nor the `dir` variables are updated. They remain the default values no matter what I do.

Custom config file:

```
daemonize yes
cluster-enabled no
dir /redis/storage
port 6397
save 60 5
save 300 1
appendonly yes
```

I’ve tried using a config map to create the custom config file then using the `spec.template.spec.containers.command/spec.template.spec.containers.args` to copy the custom config file (named redis-stack.conf) to `/etc/`, where there’s a redis-stack.conf file, which does get overwritten with the data in the custom config file. After the copy command, I have `redis-stack-server /etc/redis-stack.conf`. When I do `kubectl apply -f <filename>.conf`, then get a bash shell for one of the created pods and do `redis-cli CONFIG GET DIR` it returns the default dir.

I’ve tried adding `redis-cli CONFIG SET DIR <custom dir>` at the end of the `spec.template.spec.containers.command/spec.template.spec.containers.args` string, but that didn’t work either. There are no errors in the logs and nothing but successful events.

I’ve searched the web, but the answers I’ve found that deal with a similar problem don’t solve my issue.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out. The only way I could get it to use a custom persistence directory was to add the directory as a command line argument when I started redis-stack-server in the spec.template.spec.containers.args (where spec.template.spec.containers.command is [“sh”, “-c”]). So spec.template.spec.container.args is `redis-stack-server /path/to/custom-config.conf --dir /path/to/mounted/persistent-volume`. This loads everything from the custom config file (except daemonize, which I think actually needs to be no in my case anyway) and also properly sets the custom persistence directory.

It’s amazing what taking a two week break from working on something can do for problem-solving. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this

```
redis-stack-server redis-stack.conf --dir /path/to/data --daemonize yes
```